# HTML output using Python 3/sqlite3

Tags: python, html, sqlite

Newbie to Python and SQLLite: @ http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html - "Command Line Shell For SQLite" I found this:

***Changing Output Formats:
The sqlite3 program is able to show the results of a query in eight different formats: "csv", "column", "html", "insert", "line", "list", "tabs", and "tcl". You can use the ".mode" dot command to switch between these output formats.***

Question: How to do this with the bundled SQLite package that comes with Python 3 - I can open a connection, get a cursor, execute SQL etc but I can't figure out how to use the *.mode html* command - or any of the dot commands.

Here's an example program - but I want to output the results 'print(l)' on last line in html format using  sqlite .mode html

```
import sqlite3
def main():

    conn = sqlite3.connect('c:\dbTest.dat')
    curs=conn.cursor()
    fs='insert into test(token) values ("%s")'
    i=0
    x=input("Enter a number please: ")
    x.lstrip()
    x=int(x)
    while i<x:
        s=fs % ("ABCD"+str(i/0.999)) 
        curs.execute(s)
        i=i+1
    conn.commit()
    rows=curs.execute('select token from test')
    l=rows.fetchall()
    print(l)

main();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: The various dot commands are features of the `sqlite3` program, they're not part of the SQLite database library. AFAIK you'll have to produce the HTML yourself if you need HTML output. Or you could talk to `sqlite3` using some pipes but that's probably more trouble that it is worth.

Comment: @mu is too short, [aspw](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/) can provide `.mode` support in python

Comment: @Mike: Nice, thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite's html mode is part of a wrapper that is not included in `python`, but you can use the [aspw](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/) module to access it...

```
import apsw
import StringIO as io
output=io.StringIO()
conn = apsw.Connection('dbTest.dat')
shell=apsw.Shell(stdout=output, db=conn)
# How to execute a dot command
shell.process_command(".mode html")
# continue
```

See [the ASPW example](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/source/browse/example-code.py) for more details

EDIT

If you are using python3...

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:29:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import io
>>> import apsw
>>> output = io.StringIO()
>>> conn = apsw.Connection(":memory:")
>>> shell = apsw.Shell(stdout=output, db=conn)
>>> shell.process_command(".mode html")
>>>
```

Comment: @Mike -"part of a wrapper that is not included in python" - I was afraid that might be the problem. Will have to look into the apsw module and then I can accept your answer. Tnx

Comment: @Mikey, no worries.  Take your time

Comment: @Mike - I installed apsw for P 3.2 but can't run your code: where is StringIO module? I don't have it. And  on "conn = apsw.Connection('e:\dbTest.dat') I get this error:
 builtins.AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Connection'" - tnx

Comment: @Mikey, please see my edit... try `io.StringIO()` under python3.  I'm not sure why you're having problems with `apsw.Connection()`.  How did you install `apsw`?  I installed with their binary python3.2 installer, and as you can see I am using `apsw.Connection()` in my IDLE session above.

Comment: @mike - got the edit - understood. I installed apsw with binary installer package they supply on their website - it found my python 3.2 and installed and I was able to import the library.But it didn't recognize Connection() as you can see maybe there is something dependent on io? I'll try again tonight. I am using Wing IDE, which has been solid as rock but I'll try with IDLE. Tnx.

Comment: I'm the author of APSW.  apsw.Connection definitely works and has been in the codebase since day 1 (2004).  You are welcome to contact me via email - address on the home page http://code.google.com/p/apsw/ and I'll help out.  The APSW shell lets you do HTML output.  However the code that actually does that isn't very long - ultimately each row of results is iterated over and an HTML row generated - you could just as easily do the same thing in your code.